# Include related entity in the controller

Tags: entity-framework

When executing my `GetPlans` request, it doesn't include all the related classes

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PlansController : Controller
{
    private readonly YnynContext _context;

    public PlansController(YnynContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Plans
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetPlans")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
          return _context.Plans != null ? 
                      Ok(await _context.Plans.ToListAsync()) :
                      Problem("Entity set 'YnynContext.Plans'  is null.");
    }
}

public class Room
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Plan> Plans { get; set; }

    public CategoryEnum Category { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Plan> BuyerPlans { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Plan> SellerPlans { get; set; }

}

public class Plan
{
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    public User Buyer { get; set; }
    public User Seller { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }

}
```

And my OnModelCreating looks like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Plan>().HasOne(a => a.Buyer).WithMany(b => b.BuyerPlans).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Plan>().HasOne(a => a.Seller).WithMany(b => b.SellerPlans).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Plan>().HasOne(a => a.Room).WithMany(b => b.Plans).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
```

I tried

```
Ok(await _context.Plans.Include(a => a.Buyer)
                       .Include(b => b.Seller)
                       .ToListAsync())
```

but it seems to create cycle error.

How do I include related classes?

Here is the actual response from the request:

```
[
  {
    "planId": 1,
    "buyer": null,
    "seller": null,
    "room": null,
    "status": "INPROGRESS",
    "documents": null
  }
]
```

Comment: Side note: `_context.Plans` is never `null`.

Comment: Right, this controller was generated with EntityFramework, just changed View() as Ok(). Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `.Include()` the related data, for example

```cs
var person = await _context.People
    .Where(p => p.Id == id)
    .Include(p => p.Address)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Or better yet, `.Select()` the data into appropriate DTOs

```cs
var person = await _context.People
    .Where(p => p.Id == id)
    .Select(p => new PersonDto {
        Name = p.Name,
        Age = p.Age,
        // ...
        Address = new AddressDto {
            Street = p.Address.Street,
            City = p.Address.City,
            // ...
        }
    })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: The thing with Include is that it throws an error : 

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.Plans.Room.Plans.Room.Plans.Room.Plans.Room.Plans.Room.Plans.Room.Plans.Room.Plans.Room.Plans.Room.Plans.Room.RoomId.
```

Comment: @MA-Moustache one of the reasons why `.Select()` is the better option. If your `AddressDto` doesn't reference `PersonDto`, you won't have a cyclic dependency.

Comment: Thank you ! I also included NewtonsoftJson in the project, but using Select and map it in a DTO is probably a "cleaner" way to do it as I can map the properties that I want.